# How to redirect views of entity types (bean) for user roles?

Tags: users, redirection, entities, blocks

[RabbitHole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) does not provide this functionality for bean blocks and [Entity Bundle Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/entity_bundle_redirect) does not seem to work. There is a user role which may edit bean blocks but I want to prevent them from viewing the bean block itself, it rather gets included via php/ views on different nodes.

How can you do that?

EDIT

this is the way the bean blocks are printed

```
<?php
    $bean_left = bean_load(2);
    print render(bean_view($bean_left));
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused by what your question is, you have bean blocks setup and you want to allow user roles to edit bean blocks, but prevent them from viewing it? And only certain bean blocks?

Comment: well the bean block detail page (/block/delta) is not supposed to be viewed since it does get rendered via php elsewhere throughout the website. so they shall edit the block but not see its detail page, but be able to see the fully rendered block when being included via render()

Answer (score 0):

From quick view of [RabbitHole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) I would suspect that it doesnt support blocks. One way to prevent this could be to use [hook_block_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7) and drop the data when comparing the url. Something like

```
function MYMODULE_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
  // Remove the data if some page view, possibly
  // this would also disable the data on bean/123/delete... :/
  // mayby instead dpm($block) with devel for better targeting? 
  if (arg(0)=='bean' && arg(2) !='edit') {
    unset($data['content']);
    //or redirect
    //drupal_goto('somepage');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bean module provides this out of the box (if I understand your question properly).

If you make sure the user doesn't have the 'View Bean page' permission (go to admin/people/permissions) then they will still be able to edit the bean blocks (provided they have the correct editing permission) but they won't be able to use the beam pages (they will get access denied errors).

Then you can just put the beans where you want around the site and users can see them there. Users who have permission can edit the beans via contextual links if you have that module enabled (it's a drupal core module) and they have permissions to use contextual links.

There isn't really any need to have a redirect in my opinion although you could still pursue the redirect if you prefer that.

Comment: i thought so too but it doesnt work. if i deny to view the bean block, it wont be included via php ):

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the way you are including the bean in the page then, can you post your code for that to your original post?

Comment: please see my updated question